# Wicket AjaxTabbedPanel with tab content panels that defer rendering until tab is activated

Tags: wicket

I have a page with an AjaxTabbedPanel with lots of tabs with content like charts, reports, etc., whose content is quite expensive to produce. Most users spend most of their time on the first panel and don't need to venture to the tabs with charts, reports etc.,

To avoid unnecessary work on the back end and provide a faster initial page render I thought it would be advantageous to avoid doing the work to populate a tab's contents until (and only if) the user clicks on a tab to activate and thus render that tab's content.

Of course the first tab will always load during initial page load as that is the one that is active by default but the other tabs' contents will lay dormant until the user clicks on the corresponding tab, avoiding doing any work for those dormant panels until necessary.

Is that possible?

I thought that I could possibly employ the AjaxLazyLoadedPanel but it seems to be designed for a different purpose and the lazy loaded panel is regularly polled until it is 'ready' but that's not what I need in my case: there's no need for polling, we will know when to render a panel's content i.e. when activation of the panel occurs.

Answer (score 2):

TabbedPanel does not need a tab's content as long at is isn't shown.

Make sure that you implement ITab#getPanel() 'lazy', i.e. the panel is created only when that method is called the first time. See PanelCachingTab for inspiration.

Comment: I'm currently using Bootstrap with its own JS powered tab activator/deactivator. Presumably if I need to switch to a Wicket AjaxTabbedPanel I need to remove the Bootstrap tab activator/deactivator stuff as AjaxTabbedPanel should do Wicket driven JS instead?

Comment: Looking at PanelCachingTab it looks like I can simply wrap each existing tab panel inside a PanelCachingTab and it should achieve the aim (in addition to switching to AjaxTabbedPanel)